# Specify title of a doxygen auto-gen class

Tags: doxygen

Is there any way to specify the title of a class page auto generated by doxygen? So instead of "ClassName Class Reference" at the top of the page I could use my own text?

Or if not my own text I'd settle for just displaying "ClassName" (without the "Class Reference").

The screenshot below shows in green the text I am trying to get rid of ... so on this page I would like the title to simply be "WindSpeedSetting". Or even more ideally I'd like the title to be "WindSpeedSetting Table".

[image]

Here is an excerpt from my doxy file:

```
<navindex>
  <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title=""/>
  <tab type="classes" visible="no" title="">
    <tab type="classlist" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
    <tab type="classindex" visible="no" title=""/>
    <tab type="hierarchy" visible="no" title=""/>
    <tab type="classmembers" visible="no" title=""/>
  </tab>
  <tab type="usergroup" url="[none]" visible="yes" title="Tables">
    <tab type="usergroup" url="[none]" visible="yes" title="SCADA">
      ...
      <tab type="user" title="WindSpeedSetting" url="@ref Radiance::Model::Scada::v12::WindSpeedSetting" />
    </tab>
    ...
  </tab>
</navindex>

<class>
  <briefdescription visible="no"/>
  <detaileddescription title="Description"/>
  <memberdef>
    <inlineclasses title=""/>
    <typedefs title=""/>
    <enums title=""/>
    <constructors title=""/>
    <functions title="" visible="no"/>
    <related title=""/>
    <variables title=""/>
    <properties title="Columns"/>
    <events title=""/>
  </memberdef>
  <allmemberslink visible="no"/>
  <usedfiles visible="no"/>
  <authorsection visible="no"/>
</class>
```

And then my C# class looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// \class WindSpeedSetting
/// A list of available anemometers in the system.
/// </summary>
public class WindSpeedSetting
{
  /// <summary>
  /// \property AlarmSpeed
  /// \a float <br /><br />
  /// </summary>
  public virtual double AlarmSpeed { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// \property AlarmTime
  /// \a bigint <br /><br />
  /// </summary>
  public virtual TimeSpan AlarmTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1. We have exactly the same issue. This has been bothering us a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a DoxygenLayout.xml you can create one following the steps described under [Changing the layout of pages](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) by the doxygen manual.

At the top of the file, you'll find the `<navindex>` tag containing the `classes` tab .

```
<navindex>
...
<tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="">
  <tab type="classes" visible="no" title="THISISANEXAMPLE"/>
  <tab type="classindex" visible="$ALPHABETICAL_INDEX" title="THISISMYTITLE"/> 
  <tab type="hierarchy" visible="yes" title=""/>
  <tab type="classmembers" visible="yes" title=""/>
</tab>
...
```

focus on `title=`"THISISANEXAMPLE"`and`visible="no"`, to change visibility and/or title and you are finished.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I guess I'm trying to change something inside the `<class>` tags?

Comment: do you get the DoxygenLayout.xml and can you see the `<navindex>`, if so and you want to get rid of `Class Reference` put `<tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="THISISANEXAMPLE"/>` set `classindex hierarchy classmembers visible="no"` that should do the trick. Play around a little and if it doesn't work maybe you can post some some of your code. It's really difficult to tell whats wrong without exact parameters and a screenshot or something would also be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed the source code of Doxygen from github and traced the "Class Reference" string to be a routine defined at line 585 of translate_en.h, specifically:

```
/*! used as the title of the HTML page of a class/struct/union */
virtual QCString trCompoundReference(const char *clName,
                                ClassDef::CompoundType compType,
                                bool isTemplate)
{
  QCString result=(QCString)clName;
  switch(compType)
  {
    case ClassDef::Class:      result+=" Class"; break;
    case ClassDef::Struct:     result+=" Struct"; break;
    case ClassDef::Union:      result+=" Union"; break;
    case ClassDef::Interface:  result+=" Interface"; break;
    case ClassDef::Protocol:   result+=" Protocol"; break;
    case ClassDef::Category:   result+=" Category"; break;
    case ClassDef::Exception:  result+=" Exception"; break;
    default: break;
  }
  if (isTemplate) result+=" Template";
  result+=" Reference";
  return result;
}
```

Which means the only way to make the "Class Reference" text disappear is either changing the language which will just replace "Class Reference" with a foreign language equivalent or patch the code.

Answer (score 0):

To show the class name without the "Class Reference" string after it you can check the tag HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE.